# How to convert a decimal number into percentage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to convert some decimal numbers present in the XML document into percentages using JavaScript but the code seems to be not working. Here is the html text :

```
fols is <num> .595498</num><br/>
wif isa <num>.0656</num><br/>
dewi is <num>.6949</num><br/>
```

Now here is the JavaScript I used :

```
function changeNumbers(){
    for(i=1; i<= document.getElementByTagName("num").length; i++){
        if(1<document.getElementByTagName("num").value<0){
            UNum = document.getElementByTagName("num").value;
            UNum = Math.round(UNum*100) + '&#37;';
            return UNum;


        }
    }
};
document.getElementByTagName("num").innerHTML = changeNumbers();
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0gy7668o/8/)

Can someone please push me in the right direction with the above JavaScript code. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` , Element**s** not Element

Comment: @OsamaMohamed changed it but still no success ! :(

Comment: Your if-loop is wrong. You ask that the value is bigger then 1 and smaller then 0.

Comment: @ThomasS lol what a petty mistake ! :'D But still the code doesn't work

Comment: `'use strict';` at the beginning of your js should help you finding some of the errors

Comment: Thanks @AntiHeadshot that trick comes in handy for finding errors in the script ! :D

Comment: @Geniusknight You're wellcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [following](http://jsfiddle.net/0gy7668o/9/):

```
function changeNumbers(){
var numElements = document.getElementsByTagName("num");
for(i=0; i<= numElements.length; i++){
    var val = parseFloat(numElements[i].innerHTML);
    if(0 < val && val < 1) {
        numElements[i].innerHTML = Math.round(val * 100);
    }
}
};
changeNumbers();
```

Comment: As a comment for if you have this in the futur, you can only use .value on form elements.

Comment: Awesome Bro ! worked like a charm, hmm so .value wasn't working in my code but worked with .innerHTML . True that @ThomasS

Comment: I'm glad I could help